# Logical AND operation in Realm android

Tags: android, realm

In the business logic I have to use Logical AND operation in my query in realm but after a lot of search I have still not found any reference for it 
In iOS realm  has provided [nspredicate](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/) but there is none for android
,Right now I'm able to do only Logical OR operation

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(ApplicationCotroller.getRealmConfig(getContext(), Constants.SCHEMA_LIVE));
     RealmResults<DummyClass> realmResults = realm.where(DummyClass.class)
     .contains("fieldName", value,Case.INSENSITIVE).or().contains("fieldName2", value,Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

AND is automatically implied in the Android Query API. You can read more about it here: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#logical-operators

But this

```
realm.where(Foo.class).equalTo("name", "foo").equalTo("name", "bar");
```

really means:

```
realm.where(Foo.class).equalTo("name", "foo").and().equalTo("name", "bar");
```

Comment: do we have anything in realm for android like nspredicate in iOS

Comment: No, Android (and Realm) does not have a text based query language like NSPredicate.